# What is the purpose of subclassing the class "object" in Python?

Tags: python, object, deprecated, future-proof, new-style-class

All the Python built-ins are subclasses of `object` and I come across many user-defined classes which are too. Why? What is the purpose of the class `object`? It's just an empty class, right?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

*Note: new-style classes are the default in Python 3. Subclassing `object` is unnecessary there. Read below for more information on usage with Python 2.*

In short, it sets free magical ponies.

In long, Python 2.2 and earlier used "old style classes". They were a particular implementation of classes, and they had a few limitations (for example, you couldn't subclass builtin types). The fix for this was to create a new style of class. But, doing this would involve some backwards-incompatible changes. So, to make sure that code which is written for old style classes will still work, the `object` class was created to act as a superclass for all new-style classes.
So, in Python 2.X, `class Foo: pass` will create an old-style class and `class Foo(object): pass` will create a new style class.

In longer, see Guido's [*Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2*](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/).

And, in general, it's a good idea to get into the habit of making all your classes new-style, because some things (the `@property` decorator is one that comes to mind) won't work with old-style classes.

Comment: @thetaiko lists some other new-style-only things that are good to know about.

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: subclassing `object` effectively makes it a *new-style* class (note that this is unnecessary since automatic in Python 3.x)

For the difference between `new style` classes and `old style` classes: see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python). For the complete story: see [this nice writeup on Python Types and Objects](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html).

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the "new-style" of classes.  You can read more about it here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance and also here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

Using new-style classes will allow you to use "Python's newer, versatile features like __slots__, descriptors, properties, and __getattribute__()."

Answer (score 3):

Right, but it marks the class as a [new-style](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) class. Newly developed classes should use the `object` base because it costs little and future-proofs your code.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is that classic classes, which didn't need a superclass, had limitations that couldn't be worked around without breaking a lot of old code.  So they created the concept of new-style classes which subclass from `object`, and now you can do cool things like define properties, and subclassing `dict` is no longer an exercise in pain and strange bugs.

The details are in section 3.3 of the Python docs: [New-style and classic classes.](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Python 2.2 introduced "new style classes"](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.2.html#old-and-new-classes) which had a number of additional features relative to the old style classes which did not subclass object. Subclassing an object was the chosen way to indicate your class should be a new style class, not an old style one.