# Get subclass name?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the name of a subclass?  For example:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print type(self)

class SubFoo(Foo):
    pass

SubFoo().bar()
```

will print: `< type 'instance' >`

I'm looking for a way to get `"SubFoo"`.

I know you can do `isinstance`, but I don't know the name of the class a priori, so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: .. at least, you can use `issubclass(SubFoo, Foo)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Foo(object):
  def bar(self):
    print type(self)

class SubFoo(Foo):
  pass

SubFoo().bar()
```

Subclassing from `object` gives you new-style classes (which are not so new any more - python 2.2!) Anytime you want to work with the self attribute a lot you will get a lot more for your buck if you subclass from object. Python's docs ... [new style classes](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/). Historically Python left the old-style way `Foo()` for backward compatibility. But, this was a long time ago. There is not much reason anymore not to subclass from object.

Comment: And `Foo()` won't work on old-enough versions of Python either.

Answer (score 16):

you can use

```
SubFoo().__class__.__name__
```

which might be off-topic, since it gives you a class name :)

Answer (score 5):

`SubFoo.__name__`

And parents: `[cls.__name__ for cls in SubFoo.__bases__]`

Answer (score 3):

It works a lot better when you use new-style classes.

```
class Foo(object):
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a reminder that this issue **doesn't exist** in `Python 3.x` and
`print(type(self))` will give the *more informative* `<class '__main__.SubFoo'>` instead of bad old `< type 'instance' >`.

This is because `object` is subclassed automatically in `Python 3.x`, making every class a `new-style` class.

More discussion at [What is the purpose of subclassing the class "object" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588628/what-is-the-purpose-of-subclassing-the-class-object-in-python).

Like others pointed out, to just get the subclass name do `print(type(self).__name__)`.