# Python: get name of actual run-time class from parent class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, introspection

Edited, original question below.
As pointed out by **@MiH** this question is nearly identical to [Get subclass name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314627/get-subclass-name)

---

Is there a way to get the name of the actual/run-time class of an object rather than the name of the class where a method is defined?

I call a base class method on derived class objects (such objects do not override the method), o.__class__.__name__ gives me the name of the class of the base class, not the name of the run-time class.

Obviously I want to avoid defining a method in each derived class just to get its class name, the objective of the question is to know if there is a way to avoid that.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314627/get-subclass-name

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... where are methods coming into this? If you've got an object `o` - then presumably that's the object you want the type of and that's it?

Comment: So you're saying `o` is of type `DerivedClass`, yet `o.__class__.__name__` is `BaseClass`?  I don't think that's possible.  Show us some code.

Comment: @MiH you are right, de facto it is a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer to my question is

1) key thing: answer indicated by @MiH:  [Get subclass name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314627/get-subclass-name), chosen answer starting *"Subclassing from object gives you new-style classes..."*  ,
other answers are the usual __class__.__name__ that is **not** right for this and that question

2) trivial pedantic bit: add .__name__ , ie.  type(self).__name__