# instance has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror

im new to python and am struggling to understand why i keep getting "AttributeError: worker instance has no attribute 'workerNo'" when i call main().

```
beltLength = 5

class worker:
    def __init__(self, wId):
        workerNo = wId

def main():
    production_Line = productionLine()
    workers = []
    for index in xrange(0, beltLength*2):
        workers.append(worker(index))  
        print workers[index].workerNo
```

My thinking is that it should append 10 new worker instances with a workerNo attribute which is equal to index in a list. 
Thanks

Comment: In `__init__`: `self.workerNo = wid` - in your code the `self.` is missing. Common mistake.

Comment: Aside: since you're using 2.7, you should always make your classes subclasses of `object`, i.e. `class worker(object):`.  This will set free [magical ponies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588628/what-is-the-purpose-of-subclassing-the-class-object-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using a local variable when you should be using an instance variable.

Calling a function or method creates a new namespace, which exists only for the duration of the call. In order for the value of `workerNo` (`worker_no` would be better according to [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the standard for Python code) to persist beyond the `__init__()` method call it has to be stored in a namespace that doesn't evaporate.

Each instance has such a namespace (which is created when its class is instantiated), and the `self` (first) argument to every method call gives access to that namespace. So in your `__init__()` method you should write

```
self.workerNo = wId
```

and then you can access it from the other methods (since they also receive a `self` argument referring to the same namespace. External references to the instance can also access the instance attributes.

Comment: Thanks, this answer provided a solid explanation as to why there was an issue which has improved my understanding.

Comment: That's what we aim for! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `self` before your workerNo.

```
class worker:
    def __init__(self, wId):
        self.workerNo = wId
```

You should consider reading [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner) as to why.