# Python commutative operator override

Tags: python, operators, overriding, symmetry

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to do a symmetric operator override in Python. For example, let's say I have a class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.value + other.value
        else:
            return self.value + other
```

Then I can do:

```
a = A(1)
a + 1
```

But if I try:

```
1 + a
```

I get an error.
Is there a way to override the operator **add** so that 1 + a will work?

Comment: one thing you cannot do is `int.__add__ = something`. This is read-only.

Comment: This is how I override the add operator of int. I don't want to do that. I want to only expand my class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just implement an `__radd__` method in your class. Once the int class can't handle the addition, the `__radd__` if implemented, takes it up.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.value + other.value
        else:
            return self.value + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)


a = A(1)
print a + 1
# 2
print 1 + a
# 2
```

> For instance, to evaluate the expression x - y, where y is an instance
>   of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.

Same applies to `x + y`.

On a side note, you probably want your class to subclass `object`. See [What is the purpose of subclassing the class "object" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588628/what-is-the-purpose-of-subclassing-the-class-object-in-python)