# Operator overloading in Python: handling different types and order of parameters

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading, operators

I have a simple class that helps with mathematical operations on vectors (i.e. lists of numbers). My `Vector` can be multiplied by other instances of `Vector` *or* a scalar (`float` or `int`).

In other, more strongly typed, languages I would create a method to multiply two `vector`s and a separate method to multiply a `vector` by and `int`/`float`. I'm still pretty new to Python and am not sure how I would implement this. The only way I can think of doing it is override `__mul__()` and test the incoming parameter:

```
class Vector(object):
  ...
 def __mul__(self, rhs):
  if isinstance(rhs, Vector):
     ...
  if isinstance(rhs, int) or isinstance(rhs, float):
    ...
```

Even if I do it that way I would be forced to multiply a `Vector` by a scalar like this:

```
v = Vector([1,2,3])

result = v * 7
```

What if I wanted to reverse the order of the operands in the multiplication?

```
result = 7 * v
```

What is the right way to do that in Python?

Comment: Personally I would just use `NumPy` arrays. They already support element-wise operations (with other arrays **and** scalars). It also includes inner and outer products and accumulation functions like `sum`. That makes the task almost trivial.

Comment: I *knew* I was going to get that comment. ;-) This is a throw-away class I'm using to become familiar with Python. I am well aware of Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071861/python-commutative-operator-override

Comment: Strong vs. weak typing has no indication on whether a language has operator overloading. Scala and C++ both have operator overloading. It's only Java that doesn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You also need to implement `__rmul__`. When the initial call to `int.__mul__(7, v)` fails, Python will next try `type(v).__rmul__(v, 7)`.

```
def __rmul__(self, lhs):
    return self * lhs  # Effectively, turn 7 * v into v * 7
```

As Rawing points out, you could simply write `__rmul__ = __mul__` for this definition. `__rmul__` exists to allow for non-commutative multiplication where simply deferring to `__mul__` with the operands reversed isn't sufficient.

For instance, if you were writing a `Matrix` class and wanted to support multiplication by a nested list, e.g.,

```
m = Matrix(...)  # Some 2 x 2 matrix
n = [[1, 2], [3,4]]
p = n * m
```

Here, the `list` class wouldn't know how to multiple a list by a `Matrix` instance, so when `list.__mul__(n, m)` fails, Python would next try `Matrix.__rmul__(m, n)`. However, `n * m` and `m * n` are two different results in general, so `Matrix.__rmul__(m, n) != Matrix.__mul__(m, n)`; `__rmul__` has to do a little extra work to generate the right answer.

Comment: You almost certainly want to do `return self.__mul__(lhs)`, not `return self * lhs`; the latter implementation invokes the same "try left operator then right operator" machinery you're already running, so if `self.__mul__` returned `NotImplemented`, and `lhs` had the same broken `__rmul__` implementation, you end up with each `__rmul__` calling the other (after `__mul__` returns `NotImplemented` each time) back and forth, recursively, until you overflow the stack. Explicitly calling `__mul__` avoids that potential infinite recursion.

Answer (score 11):

There are [special methods for reversed operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

- `__rmul__` for the reverse of `__mul__`
- and `__radd__` for `__add__`,
- ...

These are called when the left hand side operator returns `NotImplemented` for the normal operation (so the operation `2 + vector_instance` will first try: `(2).__add__(vector_instance)` but if this returns `NotImplemented` then `vector_instance.__radd__(2)` is called).

However I wouldn't use `isinstance` checks in the arithmetic special methods, that will lead to a lot of code repetition.

You could actually create a special case in `__init__` and implement a conversion from scalars to a `Vector` there:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y=None, z=None):
        if y is None and z is None:
            if isinstance(x, Vector):
                self.x, self.y, self.z = x.x, x.y, x.z
            else:
                self.x, self.y, self.z = x, x, x
        elif y is None or z is None:
            raise ValueError('Either x, y and z must be given or only x')
        else:
            self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z

    def __mul__(self, other):
        other = Vector(other)
        return Vector(self.x*other.x, self.y*other.y, self.z*other.z)

    __rmul__ = __mul__   # commutative operation

    def __sub__(self, other):
        other = Vector(other)
        return Vector(self.x-other.x, self.y-other.y, self.z-other.z)

    def __rsub__(self, other):   # not commutative operation
        other = Vector(other)
        return other - self

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vector({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z})'.format(self=self)
```

This should work as expected:

```
>>> 2 - Vector(1, 2, 3)
Vector(1, 0, -1)

>>> Vector(1, 2, 3) - 2
Vector(-1, 0, 1)

>>> Vector(1, 2, 3) * 2
Vector(2, 4, 6)

>>> 2 * Vector(1, 2, 3)
Vector(2, 4, 6)
```

Note that this was a quick and dirty draft (that could have several bugs). I just wanted to present the "general idea" how it could be solved without special casing the type in each arithmetic operation.

Comment: Thank you for the ' __rmul__ = __mul__` tip. I wouldn't have known that was possible in Python.