# How does Python determine operand precedence for ==?

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading, equals

Comparing `list`s with the `==` operator returns a `bool`.

```
>>> [0,0,0] == [0,1,0]
False
```

Comparing `numpy` arrays with the `==` operator returns another array resulting from element wise comparison.

```
>>> np.array([0,0,0]) == np.array([0,1,0])
array([ True, False,  True])
```

If I mix operand types, the `numpy` method always takes precedence.

```
>>> np.array([0,0,0]) == [0,1,0]
array([ True, False,  True])
>>> [0,0,0] == np.array([0,1,0])
array([ True, False,  True])
```

How does `Python` determine which operand has precedence? My question has more to do with the mechanics of `Python` than with `numpy` or `list`.

Comment: If `==` is a numpy operation, it will effectively take the RHS and throw an `np.asarray()` around it to coerce it into a numpy array. This is **not** called operator precedence.

Comment: What does it mean for `==` to be a `numpy` operation? Does it mean that the `array` is on the LHS? If so, your answer makes sense, but how does it resolve if the `array` is on the RHS?

Comment: `list.__eq__` vs `np.ndarray.__eq__`

Comment: Yes, but how does `==` know whether to use list.__eq__ or np.ndarray.__eq__? Does it determine this based on the LHS operand, or some other criteria?

Comment: My *guess* is that `list.__eq__` fails then `np.ndarray.__eq__` is tried. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521074/operator-overloading-in-python-handling-different-types-and-order-of-parameters

Comment: It isn't an issue of operator precedence, there is only one operator. Basically, a well define comparison operators hook, like `__eq__` will return `NotImplemented` if it doesn't recognize what to do with the other type, and then the comparison defers to that types `__eq__` read about it in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rich comparison operators always ask the left operand first (unless the right operand is an instance of a subclass of the type of the left; not the case here). If the first operand checked returns `NotImplemented` (which `list` will always do when comparing to `numpy` arrays, since it can't possibly have knowledge of them baked in to the core interpreter), then the second operand's is asked to perform the reflected comparison (which doesn't change for `__eq__`).

Since `numpy` baked knowledge of `list` into its `__eq__`, and `list` didn't bake in knowledge of `numpy` arrays, `numpy` either goes first and uses its own logic immediately (when it's the left operand) or `list` goes first (when it's the left operand), gives up by returning `NotImplemented`, then `numpy`'s `__eq__` makes the final call.

Rough internals of `left == right` call (omitting subclass special case):

```
attempt = type(left).__eq__(left, right)
if attempt is NotImplemented:
   attempt = type(right).__eq__(right, left)
   if attempt is NotImplemented:
       attempt = False  # Specific to __eq__, if both can't compare, returns False
return attempt
```

For full details, start from [the `NotImplemented` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=notimplemented#NotImplemented) and follow the yellow brick road (read: links).

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the left operand is always evaluated before the right operand. That also applies to function arguments.

Python uses short circuiting when evaluating expressions involving the `and` or `or` operators. When using those operators, Python does not evaluate the second operand unless it is necessary to resolve the result. That allows statements such as `if (s != None)` and `(len(s) < 10): ...` to work reliably.

`year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0`