code walkthrough of chain syntax in langchain
I am following a RAG tutorial from: https://medium.com/@vndee.huynh/build-your-own-rag-and-run-it-locally-langchain-ollama-streamlit-181d42805895
In the tutorial there is a section that creates a chain:
        self.chain = ({"context": self.retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
                      | self.prompt
                      | self.model
                      | StrOutputParser())

Can somebody explain what this block of code does? The syntax is unfamiliar to me. My best understanding is that:
the pipe operator feeds the output of the last function to the others. so this can be re-written as:
query = {"context": self.retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
prompt = self.prompt(query)
response = self.model(prompt)
string_out = StrOutputParser(response)
chain(string_out)

In the example, self.chain is invoked as follows:
self.chain.invoke(query) # query is a str

and the following are the properties defined on the main object:
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser

# ...

class ChatPDF:
  def __init__(self):
    self.prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(
            """
            <s> [INST] Vous êtes un assistant pour les tâches de réponse aux questions. Utilisez les éléments de contexte suivants pour répondre à la question. 
            Si vous ne connaissez pas la réponse, dites simplement que vous ne savez pas.. Utilisez trois phrases
             maximum et soyez concis dans votre réponse. [/INST] </s> 
            [INST] Question: {question} 
            Context: {context} 
            Answer: [/INST]
            """)
    self.model = ChatOllama(model="mistral")
    # ...

The whole code can be viewed on the medium blogpost
In summary, I would like an explanation of what this block of code does, and I am especially confused about the following:

How can we pass input to self.model? self.model is not a function, it is a ChatOllama that has already been constructed. So what's happening here?
What does RunnablePassthrough() do? I read the documentation and it seems to just be an identity function. Why do we need this?(https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/expression_language/primitives/passthrough/) I assume when you write self.chain.invoke(query) then RunnablePassthrough() == query
why is the whole expression wrapped in parentheses? I assume this has something to do with langchain and also the pipe operator. When I mess around and make variables like test = (print); test("hi") vs test = print; test("hi") the results are the same

Edit: someone said this is similar to How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python? , but it is not. The pipe operator is being used in this example to merge dicts where here it is being used to pass outputs of functions to the next, afaik. No dicts here. The pipe operator is overloaded in python.

Generally speaking, "please explain this code" questions are categorically too broad to be on-topic here unless they narrowly identify a single, specific technical problem.

(as for the parenthesis, though -- you could take them out if you added backslashes as line continuations or collapsed to one line, but both those changes would make the code uglier; that part of the question is duplicative of When is a Python operator a line continuation? -- nothing specific to langchain)

"The pipe operator is being used in this example to merge dicts where here it is being used to pass outputs of functions to the next, afaik", well you didn't know and the pipe operator is used to merge dictionaries here, too.

@mkrieger1 where are the dictionaries?

Here: {"context": self.retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}

@mkrieger1 Yet the objects following it are: a PromptTemplate, a ChatOllama, and a StringOutputParser, none of which (as best I understand it) can be easily represented as dictionaries?

langchain-core's Runnable interface specifies __or__ to create a new RunnableSerializable connecting the inputs on either side.

(If the question were narrowed to where that -- which is to say, "how does langchain-core allow bitwise-or between objects of different types?" or such -- were explicitly the only thing you were asking, I'd be up for reopening it).

(btw, you might find it useful, in a repl, to inspect PromptTemplate.__or__, ChatOllama.__or__, and StringOutputParser.__or__; you can also import inspect and then investigate what inspect.getsourcefile(StringOutputParser.__or__) evaluates to).

@mkrieger1, do you mind that I replaced your duplicate rather than adding others to the list in addition?

@CharlesDuffy That seems fine to me. One thing I would personally find interesting is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521074/operator-overloading-in-python-handling-different-types-and-order-of-parameters, i.e. what are the rules as to whether dict's or langchain's overload will be used.

@mkrieger1, ...agreed, added.
