# Incrementing class variables dynamically in Python

Tags: python

I have a simple class, and every time I create an instance of that class, I want the class variable to increment how is should i do that with this code:

```
class Person:

    person_count = 0

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

ashley = Person("Ash")
daphne = Person("Daph")

Person.person_count #I want this to be 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply increment the class variable in `__init__`:

```
class Person(object):

    person_count = 0

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        Person.person_count += 1  # here

ashley = Person("Ash")
daphne = Person("Daph")

print(Person.person_count)
# 2
```

And don't forget to subclass from `object` if you're on Python 2.

See [What is the purpose of subclassing the class "object" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588628/what-is-the-purpose-of-subclassing-the-class-object-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to increment the class's variable within the `__init__` as:

```
class Person:
    person_count = 0
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.__class__.person_count += 1
        # OR, 
        # Person.person_count += 1
```

Example:

```
>>> ashley = Person("Ash")
>>> ashley.person_count
1
>>> daphne = Person("Daph")
>>> daphne.person_count
2
```

You may also extract the count directly using class as:

```
>>> Person.person_count
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__init__` method in order to increase your class variable:

```
class Person:
    person_count = 0
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        Person.person_count += 1
```

A class variable can be access using the name of the class, so in this case `Person`. Keep in mind that you can also access this class variable from the instance, so:

```
>>> p1 = Person('person1')
>>> Person.person_count
1
>> p1.person_count
1
>> p2 = Person('person2')
>>> Person.person_count
2
>> p1.person_count
2
>> p2.person_count
2
```