# Using Objects In Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, object

In this **(test)** code:

```
class Test(object):
  def __init__(self,val):
    self.val=val
  def returnVal(self):
    return(self.val)

dict = {}
dict["Tom"] = Test(20)
```

How do I get Tom to use the 'returnVal' function. As Tom.returnVal() doesn't seem to work. (Sorry if this is a silly question, this is my first time using dictionaries for objects.

Comment: You can also do `dict.get("Tom").returnVal()`. Also your  question is nice but may I tell you that some people might not like it & downvote it so probably in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should change the codes a little bit

```
class Test(object):

  def __init__(self,val):
    self.val=val
  def returnVal(self):
    return self.val   # return not only print

dict = {}
dict["Tom"] = Test(20)
```

And Tom is not an object, it is a key of the dict. So you should code  like this:

```
dict["Tom"].returnVal()
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the key value to select the element from the dictionary, just like you did when you assigned it.

`dict["Tom"].returnVal()`

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few more things you can learn that are relevant in your post.

First, since Python 3.x you do not need to sub-class your classes from `object`. It is automatic. See [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588628/what-is-the-purpose-of-subclassing-the-class-object-in-python) (including some relevant comments).

So you can probably do:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value

  def value(self):
    return self.value
```

You might consider if you really want the method `value`. In Python, if the only thing you need is to read an attribute value (no additional processing, no access control, no nothing), there is no need for a *getter* method. Accessing the attribute directly from the instance will do:

```
obj = Test(42)
value = obj.value
```

Additionally the naming style for methods and functions in Python should be `snake_case`, with `CamelCase` for class names. For other styles see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Even more important, do not assign to built-in names, such as `dict` or `list`:

```
# do not do this
dict = {}
dict["Tom"] = Test(20)
```

To see other names you should avoid using, do in the Python shell:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> dir(builtins)
```

This is because you replace the built-in definition, and you will get confused in later code. In your code above `dict` is from now on a specific dictionary instance object, and creating a new dictionary with `dict()` will fail.

Maybe you just wanted to create an object with

```
tom = Test(20)
print(tom.value)
```

Or to store Test objects (or objects of any type) in a dict:

```
people = {}
people["Tom"] = Test(20)
print(people["Tom"].value)
print("Tom" in people)
```